# Unity Physics Sphere Movement (wheel movement)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm making a sphere move over a plane object. I'm trying to make the movement similar to the movement of a wheel, but I don't want to use the Wheel Collider component. I am using torque to move the sphere back and forth and I am using the rigidbody rotation (Because I read that it is not a good practice to perform these transformations directly on the geometry), but the rotation (steering) part is not working, the sphere continues to follow in same direction even rotating. Here's code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float maxTorque = 30.0f;
    float maxSteerAngle = 30.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var deltaRotation = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(maxSteerAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = deltaRotation;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(new Vector3(maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0)); 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cache your `GetComponent` calls to improve performance (see below)
2. You are applying torque into global x direction, you probably want to move "forward" (depending on the rotation of the wheel). `transform.forward` is your friend

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;

   public class SphereMovement : MonoBehaviour
   {
       float maxTorque = 30.0f;
       float maxSteerAngle = 30.0f;
       private Rigidbody rb;

       void Start()
       {
           rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       }

       void FixedUpdate()
       {
           var deltaRotation = rb .rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(maxSteerAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));

           GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = deltaRotation;

           GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(transform.forward * (maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime); 

       }
   }
   ```

If your setup is otherwise rotated, you can try `transform.right` or `transform.up`

---

**edit**:

when you rotate your wheel, the "forward" will spin as well, so you need to ignore the `y`. (assuming an almost flat surface for now, you mentioned a plane)

So you *would* think this works:

```
Vector3 direction = transform.forward;
direction.y = 0;
direction = direction.normalized;

GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(direction * (maxTorque * 
Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
```

But Then it would go back or forth, depending on the current rotation.
So that won't work.

**Another Idea**: You could add an empty parent and rotate that on the y axis to "steer" while the child is rotated to do the actual "forward movement" like a wheel rooling over concrete.

**Option without parent**:

You simply apply Torque in local space using [Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html)

Like this (we use `Vector3.forward`, don't confuse it with `transform.forward`! Vector3.forward is simply Vector3(0, 0, 1). but in local space that's fine because the rotation is still considered)

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    var deltaRotation = rb .rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(maxSteerAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = deltaRotation;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.forward * (maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried to do as you said, and it even worked when the wheel was stopped it went in the direction I rotated but after it is in movement if I try to rotate it it goes crazy, rotating wrong. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: ooh I have an Idea, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(new Vector3(maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
```

Your torque is always being applied along the global X axis, so it doesn't matter which way the sphere object is rotated. Think of it like this -- no matter which way you rotate a soccer ball, if you spin it in a northwards direction, it will roll north. For your approach to work, you need to take your torque force and apply it along the vector you want to move, rather than always the global X axis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I tried but it only worked when the wheel was stopped. Then when in motion it rotated wrong. Would you know why?